# Creating in-memory QgsRasterlayer from the rasterization of a QgsVectorLayer with PyQGIS?

Tags: python, gdal, qgis

I am currently building a QGIS plugin and I need to rasterize a vector layer where the output will be stored in memory.

To do so, I tried this (which come from the answer from [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218475/creating-in-memory-raster-layer-using-pyqgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)) :

```
temp = processing.run("gdal:rasterize",
                           {"INPUT": input_shapefile,
                            "FIELD": "OBJECTID",
                            "UNITS": 1,
                            "WIDTH": resolution,
                            "HEIGHT": resolution,
                            "EXTENT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                            "NODATA": -99,
                            "OUTPUT": None})
```

The problem is that it does not work : None is not recognized as a valid output. I also tried "OUTPUT" : "memory" but it is not working neither... So I wonder if this answer that I found in the link above is correct ?

Note : QGIS version : 3.4.7 with Python 3.7

Comment: Did you also try "OUTPUT": "none" ? One of them is correct, `None` or `"none"`, so maybe your issue is unrelated to the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @lusitanica. I do not get error message anymore with "none", but I can't use it after in my code since I get "none : No such file or directory" by doing '''rlayer = self.iface.addRasterLayer(temp["OUTPUT"], "Rasterisation")''', which seems logical... Do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: Actually, it requires to do "result = processing.getObject(temp["OUTPUT"])" to use it, but this module seems to be no longer available in QGIS (see (this link) [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250404/processing-getobject-in-qgis-3]).

Comment: Apparently, you'll have to use `QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString()` instead, because `getObject()` was replaced with the `getLayerFromString()` method, and moved to the `QgsProcessingUtils` namespace.

Comment: Yes I already tried it but I got the message "AttributeError: type object 'QgsProcessingUtils' has no attribute 'getLayerFromString'"...

Comment: And `mapLayerFromString`?

Comment: I tried too by doing "result = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(temp["OUTPUT"])" but I got the error message "not enough arguments". The [documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Processing/QgsProcessingUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString) mentions a context but I don't understand what to put...

Comment: Declare `context = QgsProcessingContext()` and then something like
`layer= QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(Layer, context)`

Comment: I was just doing it and it worked ! But it seems that "self.iface.addRasterLayer" can't display it, do you know why ?

Comment: `qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer`

Comment: If i'm right, your code is related to the python console in Qgis, while mine is related to a plugin. The code I wrote is functional in a plugin but not in this case.

Comment: I think `self.iface.addRasterLayer` requires a file as argument, can you confirm it?

Comment: Yes, actually my complete code is : ```context = QgsProcessingContext()
 result = QgsProcessingUtils.mapLayerFromString(temp["OUTPUT"],context)
 rlayer = self.iface.addRasterLayer(result, "Rasterisation")```

Comment: So there is a problem with the result but I don't know how to manipulate a mapLayer there is no examples on the web...

Comment: Actually, your first answer didn't work. I forgot to open the Processing tab in QGIS and it is written : "  FAILURE: No output file specified."...

Comment: Could be. Can't confirm. Last time I used QGIS was 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an aswer to my question using "tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()" in the following way :

```
tf = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
tfolder = tf.name + "\\rasterisation.tif"
temp = processing.run("gdal:rasterize",
                       {"INPUT": input_shapefile,
                        "FIELD": "OBJECTID",
                        "UNITS": 1,
                        "WIDTH": resolution,
                        "HEIGHT": resolution,
                        "EXTENT": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
                        "NODATA": -99,
                        "OUTPUT": tfolder})
 rlayer = self.iface.addRasterLayer(tfolder, "Rasterisation")
```

See [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) for more information on this module.